# What is this technically called?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Long time SO reader, first time poster. I have a project that has a model which has_one Field and has_many of that same Field Model. I just want to be able to make them separately distinguishable. This is the most elegant way I've come up with.

I want to know how I should be verbally referring to the current method I'm using, and if there is better way to do this is Rails 4+.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
    # field.rb
    class Field < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user
    end

    # user.rb
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_one :primary_field, class_name: 'Field'
      has_many :secondary_fields, class_name: 'Field'
    end

u = User.create(name:"foo")
u.primary_field = Field.create(name:"ruby on rails")
u.secondary_fields << Field.create(name:"html/css") 
u.secondary_fields << Field.create(name:"javascript")
```

Edit: There was an error in my method that wasn't technically where secondary_fields weren't scoped correctly. The answer I approved fixed this.

I'd still like to know if this is referred to as something specific since it does seem like this is used relatively often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a way to distinguish which field is the primary. What you have now stores all of the fields identically, so you're going to get all three of them from the `secondary_fields` association, and the `primary_field` is effectively random (depending on what database you're using).

If you add a "primary" column to Field, you can use something like this:

```
# field.rb
class Field < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates :primary, uniqueness: {scope: user, if: :primary}
end

# user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :primary_field, -> {where(primary: true), class_name: 'Field'
  has_many :secondary_fields, -> {where(primary: false)}, class_name: 'Field'
end

u = User.create(name:"foo")
u.primary_field = Field.create(name:"ruby on rails", primary: true)
u.secondary_fields << Field.create(name:"html/css") 
u.secondary_fields << Field.create(name:"javascript")
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that. I'm also wondering if calling an association model in multiple ways with one class_name is referred to as something specific?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I end up needing this fairly regularly, and I've never come across a special term. Someone else might have one, though. I'm hardly the authoritative source :). I suppose you could call it a "filtered association," but I just made that up.

Comment: I think your answer is sufficient. I'll accept it and edit my question to see if someone has name for it. Thanks

Comment: if primary is a `boolean` field, why would you validate that it is unique? I just noticed you added that to the `Field` model

Comment: Check the scope on the validation. You need to ensure that only one field is primary for each user.

Comment: Updated answer. Needs an if check on the validation.

Comment: With this scope on the validation you can only add one secondary_field. The second would fail the validation as there would already be another field with primary=false for this user. You can add a validation to cover only the primary=true case with this: `
  validates_uniqueness_of :primary, conditions: -> { where(primary: true) }, scope: :user`

Comment: The tricky part about using a "primary" column is that you now have to take measures to ensure data integrity.You should never have two Field records with identical values for both "user_id" and "primary". A proper solution will include database constraints to prevent this from happening (ActiveRecord validations are NOT sufficient). You may also need to allow updates to change which record is marked as the primary, in which case you may need to execute some sort of trigger which is deferred until the end of a transaction (depending on which DBMS you are using).

Comment: My team uses "primary" columns like suggested in this solution. We refer to them as "mutually exclusive attributes" or simply "mutex attributes".